# Cakefile not seeing JS functions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, referenceerror, cakefile

I'm writing a Cakefile that defines a task called `build` where the following line appears:

```
coffee.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stderr.write.data.toString()
```

When I run the task with `cake build`, it throws a `ReferenceError` saying that the function `toString` is undefined.

I've tried repairing the Node installation, and re-installing CoffeeScript with `npm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```
process.stderr.write data.toString()
```

You've got an extra `.` in there.

The way you've written it is trying to call `toString()` on the `data` property of the `write` function. You're probably getting an error like `Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined`.

Comment: This is probably an appropriate time to say "FML." Thanks man!